# What is the syntax in C# .NET for the following PHP snippet? [DataTables]

Tags: c#, php, datatable

There are the conditions I'm trying to archive:

If **the selected site id** (simply called site) **is not submitted as part of the request**, **an empty data array** should be shown on the client-side.

**When the selected site information is submitted it should be used as a WHERE condition so the child table only displays data that matches that site.**

below is the PHP Where condition (I need it in C# .NET):

```
if ( ! isset($_POST['site']) || ! is_numeric($_POST['site']) ) {
    echo json_encode( [ "data" => [] ] );
}
else {
    Editor::inst( $db, 'users' )
        ->field(
            Field::inst( 'users.first_name' ),
            Field::inst( 'users.last_name' ),
            Field::inst( 'users.phone' )
        )
        ->leftJoin( 'sites', 'sites.id', '=', 'users.site' )
        ->where( 'site', $_POST['site'] )
        ->process($_POST)
        ->json();
}
```

What I have (C#):

```
DtResponse response = new Editor(WebApiApplication.Db, "users")
    .Model<JoinModelUsers>("users")
    .Model<JoinModelSites>("sites")
    .Field(new Field("users.site")
        .Options("sites", "id", "name")
        .Validator(Validation.DbValues(new ValidationOpts { Empty = false }))
    )
    .LeftJoin("sites", "sites.id", "=", "users.site")
    .Process(formData)
    .Data();
 
return Json(response);
```

THANK YOU!

Comment: What is the `Editor` type? Is this a part of some ORM?

Comment: @Dennis Yes, Datatable Editor

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I hope it helps someone else out there one day:

```
public IHttpActionResult Users()
        {
            var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
            var settings = Properties.Settings.Default;

            using (var db = new Database(settings.DbType, settings.DbConnection))
            {
                var site = "-1";
                if (request.Form.Keys.Contains("site"))
                {
                    site = request.Form["site";
                }

                var response = new Editor(db, "users")
                    .Model<JoinModelUsers>("users")
                    .Model<JoinModelSites>("sites")
                    .Field(new Field("users.site")
                        .Options(new Options()
                            .Table("sites")
                            .Value("id")
                            .Label("name")
                        )
                        .Validator(Validation.DbValues(new ValidationOpts { Empty = false }))
                    )
                    .LeftJoin("sites", "sites.id", "=", "users.site")
                    .Where("site", site)
                    .Process(Request)
                    .Data();

                return Json(response);
            }
        }
```